# Neo4j : Label Propagation with seed labels

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

I would like to apply label propagation to my data in Neo4j with seed labels and weight property. My data looks like the image.

[image]

The relationship 'Appears_in' has the weight property (integers like 8 in the image) and some articles nodes has seed label property (strings, for example Iphone).

I would like to propagate this seed labels to create clusters with the articles that speaks about the same topic, for example Iphone cluster. More precisely I would like to propagate seed label to another article node but articles do not have a direct relationship between them. They are 'somewhere' connected through the words that they have in commun...

Firstly, I ran weakly connected component in order to keep the only one big network I have in my data :

```
CALL gds.wcc.stream('lpa_test') 
YIELD nodeId, componentId 
RETURN componentId, count(*) as size 
ORDER BY size DESC 
LIMIT 1000
```

[image]

So I tried to kept the network with 2170 nodes and I projected a bipartite graph to a monopartite with the cypher projection. In the next step, I ran the Label Propagation algorithm. Here is the code :

```
CALL gds.labelPropagation.write({
  nodeQuery:"MATCH (n:ARTICLE) WHERE n.familyComponent = 0 
             RETURN id(n) as id",
  relationshipQuery:"MATCH (a:Article)<-[:APPEARS_IN]-(b:KEYWORD)-[:APPEARS_IN]->(c:Article) 
                     RETURN id(a) as source, id(c) as target, count(distinct b) as word_weight",
  relationshipWeightProperty: "word_weight",
  writeProperty: "lpa"})
```

The results are not good.

I would like to give seed labels (strings) and the weights (that are in the relationships) to the Label Propagation Algorithm.

I would like to have few clusters (I guess 5 clusters if I have 5 seed labels (strings))

I have 5 nodes with seed labels (strings) and I would like to propagate these seed labels throught the network.

For example : The 5 seed labels (strings) would be 'Iphone', 'Coronavirus', 'Disney', 'Crisis', 'Summer'.

How can I write the Label Propagation to propagate these seed labels (strings) ?

Comment: Please write code in code blocks instead of taking an image of the code.

Comment: Hello, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the seed properties to the Articles. If you look at the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/label-propagation/#algorithms-label-propagation-examples-seeded) you will notice that the description of the `seedProperty` parameter is:

> seedProperty: Used to define initial set of labels (must be a number).

This implies that you cannot use strings as seed labels, but you will have to create a mapping function that maps strings to integers. In your case that could be something like:

- Iphone: 1
- Coronavirus: 2
- Disney: 3
- Crisis: 4
- Summer: 5

After you have added the seed labels (integers) to the nodes, you can run the following query to execute the seeded Label propagation algorithm. You have to add the seed property in the `nodeQuery` and define it with the `seedProperty` parameter.

```
CALL gds.graph.create({
  nodeQuery: "MATCH (n:Article) WHERE n.familyComponent = 0
              RETURN id(n) as id, n.seedLabel as seedLabel",
  relationshipQuery:"MATCH (a:Article)<-[:APPEARS_IN]-(b:KEYWORD)-[:APPEARS_IN]->(c:Article)
                     RETURN id(a) as source, id(c) as target, count(distinct b) as word_weight",
  relationshipWeightProperty:'word_weight',
  seedProperty:'seedLabel',
  writeProperty:'lpa'

})
```

This should work. One thing to note is that the result may include more than five labels if you haven't used a seed property for all the nodes in the graph. The documentation states:

> The algorithm first checks if there is a seed label assigned to the
> node. If no seed label is present, a new unique label is assigned to
> the node. Using this preliminary set of labels, it then sequentially
> updates each node’s label to a new one, which is the most frequent
> label among its neighbors at every iteration of label propagation.

For example, if you only assign a seed label to 50% of the nodes, the other 50% of the nodes will be initiated with a random unique label. This, in turn, implies that you might end up with more than 5 communities.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm going to try it.
Is there another way to make semi-supervised learning with Neo4j to only have communities with labels that I have chosen ?